# How can I display floating point numbers in a short format and still be able to do calculations in this Vue application?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, calculator, vuejs3

I am working on a small calculator application with Vue 3 and some custom CSS.

As far as I can tell, it works fine, with *the exception of displaying long numbers as results*.

```js
const calculatorApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      operationsTrack: [],
      operations: [],
      calculation: null,
      currentVal: "",
      isOperatorClicked: false,
      isEquaSignClicked: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    appendDot() {
      if (this.currentVal.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        this.appendNumber(".");
      }
    },
    appendNumber(clickedVal) {
      if (this.isOperatorClicked) {
        this.currentVal = "";
        this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      }

      if (!this.isEquaSignClicked) {
        this.currentVal = `${this.currentVal}${clickedVal}`;
      } else {
        this.currentVal = clickedVal;
        this.operationsTrack = [];
      }

      this.operationsTrack.push(clickedVal);
    },
    doOperation(operator, operatorLabel) {
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
      this.isOperatorClicked = true;
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);
      this.operations.push(operator);
      this.operationsTrack.push(operatorLabel);
    },
    doCalculation() {
      // push the last value to the operations array
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);

      let opt = this.operations.map((i) => {
        if (!isNaN(i)) {
          return Number(i);
        }
        return i;
      });

      // Make the calulations string
      this.calculation = opt.join(" ");

      // Compute the calculations
      this.currentVal = eval(this.calculation);

      // Empty the operations array
      this.operations = [];

      // Update equal sign flag
      this.isEquaSignClicked = true;
    },
    clearDisplay() {
      this.currentVal = "";
      this.operations = [];
      this.operationsTrack = [];
      this.calculation = null;
      this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    operationsTrackDisplay() {
      return this.operationsTrack.join(" ");
    }
  }
};
Vue.createApp(calculatorApp).mount("#myCalculator");
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.calculator {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 36px;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.result,
.track {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.buttons-container ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #242424;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.buttons-container li,
.buttons-container .clear {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons-container li {
  width: 60px;
}

.buttons-container .clear {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.buttons-container .orange {
  background: #ff9800;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator" id="myCalculator">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="track">
        <span>{{operationsTrack.length ? operationsTrackDisplay + ' =' : ''}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        {{currentVal || 0}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
      <ol>
        <li @click="appendNumber('7')">7</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('8')">8</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('9')">9</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('/', '&divide;')">&divide;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('4')">4</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('5')">5</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('6')">6</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('*', '&times;')">&times;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('1')">1</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('2')">2</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('3')">3</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('-', '-')">-</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('0')">0</li>
        <li @click="appendDot('.')">&middot;</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('+', '+')">+</li>
        <li @click="doCalculation" class="orange">=</li>
      </ol>
      <div @click="clearDisplay" class="clear orange">Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### The problem

An arithmetic operation resulting in a long floating point, like `1 5 ÷ 9` which results in `1.6666666666666667` has the inconvenience of stretching off the display.

Using this as a solution is a bad idea, since `toFixed()` **converts to a string**:

```
 <div class="result">
    {{currentVal.toFixed(6) || 0}}
  </div>
```

##### What is a viable solution for displaying long floats conveniently?

Comment: Why is string a problem if it is for display only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add another computed method - e.g. `result` that would show the number in one of three formats and not alter the value in  `currentVal`:

1. scientific format - if the number is 1M or more- use [`Number.toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)
2. integer - with no mantissa- when [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) returns `true`
3. floating point number with finite number of digits - when the length of the string representation is less than the length of the string representation when calling calling `.toFixed()`
4. floating point number with fixed format - from calling `.toFixed()`

---

```
computed:
  result() {
    const number = +this.currentVal;
    if (number > 999999) { 
      return number.toExponential(4);
    }
    if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
      return this.currentVal;
    }
    const fixed = number.toFixed(6);
    if (fixed.length > this.currentVal.length) {
      return this.currentVal;
    }
    return fixed; 
  }
```

That way it can be displayed as desired.

```js
const calculatorApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      operationsTrack: [],
      operations: [],
      calculation: null,
      currentVal: "",
      isOperatorClicked: false,
      isEquaSignClicked: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    appendDot() {
      if (this.currentVal.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        this.appendNumber(".");
      }
    },
    appendNumber(clickedVal) {
      if (this.isOperatorClicked) {
        this.currentVal = "";
        this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      }

      if (!this.isEquaSignClicked) {
        this.currentVal = `${this.currentVal}${clickedVal}`;
      } else {
        this.currentVal = clickedVal;
        this.operationsTrack = [];
      }

      this.operationsTrack.push(clickedVal);
    },
    doOperation(operator, operatorLabel) {
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
      this.isOperatorClicked = true;
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);
      this.operations.push(operator);
      this.operationsTrack.push(operatorLabel);
    },
    doCalculation() {
      // push the last value to the operations array
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);

      let opt = this.operations.map((i) => {
        if (!isNaN(i)) {
          return Number(i);
        }
        return i;
      });

      // Make the calulations string
      this.calculation = opt.join(" ");

      // Compute the calculations
      this.currentVal = eval(this.calculation);

      // Empty the operations array
      this.operations = [];

      // Update equal sign flag
      this.isEquaSignClicked = true;
    },
    clearDisplay() {
      this.currentVal = "";
      this.operations = [];
      this.operationsTrack = [];
      this.calculation = null;
      this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    operationsTrackDisplay() {
      return this.operationsTrack.join(" ");
    },    
    result() {
      const number = +this.currentVal;
      if (number > 999999) { 
        return number.toExponential(4);
      }
      if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
        return this.currentVal;
      }
      const fixed = number.toFixed(6);
      if (fixed.length > this.currentVal.length) {
          return this.currentVal;
      }
      return fixed; 
    }
  }
};
Vue.createApp(calculatorApp).mount("#myCalculator");
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.calculator {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 36px;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.result,
.track {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.buttons-container ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #242424;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.buttons-container li,
.buttons-container .clear {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons-container li {
  width: 60px;
}

.buttons-container .clear {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.buttons-container .orange {
  background: #ff9800;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator" id="myCalculator">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="track">
        <span>{{operationsTrack.length ? operationsTrackDisplay + ' =' : ''}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        {{ result || 0}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
      <ol>
        <li @click="appendNumber('7')">7</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('8')">8</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('9')">9</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('/', '&divide;')">&divide;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('4')">4</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('5')">5</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('6')">6</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('*', '&times;')">&times;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('1')">1</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('2')">2</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('3')">3</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('-', '-')">-</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('0')">0</li>
        <li @click="appendDot('.')">&middot;</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('+', '+')">+</li>
        <li @click="doCalculation" class="orange">=</li>
      </ol>
      <div @click="clearDisplay" class="clear orange">Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about displaying very big numbers (like 70 billion, for instance), in a format that would not get it out of the display?

Comment: updated to have another case using [`Number.toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) for numbers larger than 999,999

Answer (score 1):

If you do this change in your calculation function, it would keep still as number

```
this.currentVal = parseFloat(eval(this.calculation).toFixed(6));
```

```js
const calculatorApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      operationsTrack: [],
      operations: [],
      calculation: null,
      currentVal: "",
      isOperatorClicked: false,
      isEquaSignClicked: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    appendDot() {
      if (this.currentVal.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        this.appendNumber(".");
      }
    },
    appendNumber(clickedVal) {
      if (this.isOperatorClicked) {
        this.currentVal = "";
        this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      }

      if (!this.isEquaSignClicked) {
        this.currentVal = `${this.currentVal}${clickedVal}`;
      } else {
        this.currentVal = clickedVal;
        this.operationsTrack = [];
      }

      this.operationsTrack.push(clickedVal);
    },
    doOperation(operator, operatorLabel) {
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
      this.isOperatorClicked = true;
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);
      this.operations.push(operator);
      this.operationsTrack.push(operatorLabel);
    },
    doCalculation() {
      // push the last value to the operations array
      this.operations.push(this.currentVal);

      let opt = this.operations.map((i) => {
        if (!isNaN(i)) {
          return Number(i);
        }
        return i;
      });

      // Make the calulations string
      this.calculation = opt.join(" ");
      // Compute the calculations
      this.currentVal = parseFloat(eval(this.calculation).toFixed(6));
      // Empty the operations array
      this.operations = [];
      // Update equal sign flag
      this.isEquaSignClicked = true;
    },
    clearDisplay() {
      this.currentVal = "";
      this.operations = [];
      this.operationsTrack = [];
      this.calculation = null;
      this.isOperatorClicked = false;
      this.isEquaSignClicked = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    operationsTrackDisplay() {
      return this.operationsTrack.join(" ");
    }
  }
};
Vue.createApp(calculatorApp).mount("#myCalculator");
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.calculator {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 36px;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.result,
.track {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.buttons-container ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #242424;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.buttons-container li,
.buttons-container .clear {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons-container li {
  width: 60px;
}

.buttons-container .clear {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.buttons-container .orange {
  background: #ff9800;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator" id="myCalculator">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="track">
        <span>{{operationsTrack.length ? operationsTrackDisplay + ' =' : ''}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        {{currentVal || 0}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
      <ol>
        <li @click="appendNumber('7')">7</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('8')">8</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('9')">9</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('/', '&divide;')">&divide;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('4')">4</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('5')">5</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('6')">6</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('*', '&times;')">&times;</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('1')">1</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('2')">2</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('3')">3</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('-', '-')">-</li>
        <li @click="appendNumber('0')">0</li>
        <li @click="appendDot('.')">&middot;</li>
        <li @click="doOperation('+', '+')">+</li>
        <li @click="doCalculation" class="orange">=</li>
      </ol>
      <div @click="clearDisplay" class="clear orange">Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```